# Automate batch sending emails for different audiences via Rake or Active Job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have 3 sets of audiences (70 people per audience), who need individualized emails sent to them at specific times. Each email needs to be customized to that specific audience: The content of the email is something like:  “Hi First_Name” you are in Audience A, and you will be sitting in “Row X, Seat Y” etc.

Audience A needs Email 1 sent on Thursday at 10:00AM, and Email 2 sent on Friday at 2:00pm, Email 3 on Saturday at 12:00pm

Audience B needs Email 1 sent on Friday at 10:00AM and Email 2 sent on Saturday at 2:00pm, Email 3 on Sunday at 12:00pm

Audience C needs Email 1 sent on Saturday at 10:00AM, Email 2 sent on Sunday at 2:00pm, Email 3 Monday at 12:00pm

What is the proper “Rails-Way” to automate and batch send these emails?  Some kind of custom rake task? Or an ActiveJob? Or can I create a button on the website, so that the box office staff can just click one button on the site and it will automatically send all of these emails?

I have a Rails 5 application that can send emails to all audiences using the deliver_now and Mailgun, based off a mouseclick. I am refactoring the application to separate the audiences more specifically and automate the delivery of emails. I don't know anything about ActiveJob and I'm a rails noobie.

patrons_controller.rb

```
def audience_segment_A
    Patron.where(audience: A).pluck(:email).batch_send
end

def batch_send
    PatronMailer.send(email_1).deliver_now
    PatronMailer.send(email_2).deliver_later(wait: 26.hours)
    PatronMailer.send(email_3).deliver_later(wait: 22.hours)
end
```

My code doesn't individualize each email, (and also doesn't work), and I'm not sure how to call/start this email sending process.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a separate table/model to stores all the e-mails (maybe `Invitation`). Add two new attributes: status (pending/sent) & time_to_sent (Datetime). Then run a rake script that queries the table for all records that are still pending and that need to be send:

```
Invitation.where(status:pending).where('time_to_send < ?', DateTime.now)
```

Then send all those mails. After successfull send, update the status accordingly.

This is probably a bit more reliable than creating Jobs. I think Jobs should be used for stuff that needs to happen right away, but of the main thread, and/or isn't business critical. You'd like to be 100% sure that the e-mails get sends probably.